# Onclick function button inside a javascript

Tags: java, php, html

I want to direct the button to another page

```
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" 
    onclick="location.href = "addnewcustomer.php";" id ="newcust" 
    class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer">';
}
```

I want when i click the New Customer button, it will redirect to addnewcustomer.php but when i run the code, nothing happened.

There are no errors. Just the button didn't function the way i want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape quotes in element. Try following code

```js
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" onclick="location.href = \'addnewcustomer.php\';" id ="newcust" class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer">';
}
```

```html
<a onclick="showInput()" >Add New Buton</a>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to redirect page.

```js
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" id ="newcust" class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer" />';
}

document.getElementById("newcust").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "addnewcustomer.php";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<a onclick="showInput()" >Click To Get Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" onclick="location.href = "yourpage.php";" id ="newcust" class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer">';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="showInput()" >Click To Get Button</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Right Click And inspect Button.

Comment: I didn’t understand the space doesn’t matter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function showInput() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" onclick="location.href = \'https://www.youtube.com/\';" class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer">';
}
showInput()
```

```html
<p id="demo">click</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you didn’t close your input tag
Try this...

```
function showInput() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" 
 onclick="location.href =     "addnewcustomer.php";" id ="newcust" 
 class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer"/>';
}
```

If you don’t close it the button will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, the inner html text is missing with escape string. Call window.onload to trigger your method and display your button. HTH.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" onclick="location.href = \'addnewcustomer.php\';" id ="newcust" class="btnRegister" value = "New Customer">';
    }
    window.onload = showInput;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```